# How can I connect to MongoDB Atlas using Robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I signed up freely at MongoDB Atlas and created cluster now I want to know how can I create database and connect to that using Robomongo?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

1) (Atlas Mongodb console)First of all click on **ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE**(see in below image) and put some random IP address , don't click on **Add Current IP Address** otherwise it will not connect with robomongo .

[image: pic1]

2) Now open robomongo ,select connection Tab and then select type Direct Connection , and put your primary cluster in Address [you can get your Primary Cluster Address from Project->Clusters->(choose) Primary Cluster-> "There you will find your Primary Cluster Address"] .

[image: pic2]

3)now click on Authentication Tab , put database name is admin and put your username and password , Auth Mechanism is SCRAM-SHA-1.

[image: pic3]

4) select self-signed certificate as Authentication Method

[image: pic4]

5)  Now , click on test,we are done !
[image: pic5]

The standard Mongo [URI connection schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) has the form:

```
 mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

**Security Reasons**

1. Do not allow access everywhere for security reasons
2. Restrict to your IP address
3. Connect via roboMongo 3T using a secondary cluster node from MongoDB Atlas

Comment: This answer helped me a lot!

Comment: @qaispak Yea ,This help me to also whenever i need it !

Comment: I get "Cannot connect...No unix socket support on Windows"

Comment: Please do not set ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE that implies you are exposing your mongodb to connections from anywhere, a very high risk and can lead to getting hacked.

Comment: @siddharthrc , i don't know because that time i was beginner ;) .Thanks for more information .

Comment: @kdblue edit the answer when you can, it would be of great help to other beginners :)

Comment: @siddharthrc  you do , thats better :)

Comment: Use SSL protocol options really helped me! Thanks!

Comment: You can (and should if you mind security of your production server) use "Add Current IP Address" - I did it today and it worked flawlessly with Robo3T

Comment: @Marecky thanks for informing us , currently i am not with robo3t so can add here?

Comment: I get: SSL tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or SSL connection rejected by server.

Comment: @EliaWeiss You need to change the database from test to admin

Answer (score 14):

In case it helps others, Robo3Tversion 1.3 and greater has a "From SRV" field where you can paste the SRV connection string and it fills out the connection options correctly for you. As of 1.3 it looks like this:

[image: From SRV]

As of writing, you can get the connection string by clicking the "connect" button next to your cluster dashboard's graphs, and then clicking "Connect your application", and you get a screen like this with the connection string that you can copy:

[image: connection string in mongodb atlas]

Comment: This worked for me in Robo 3T 1.4, very easy, just copy that connection string, make sure it contains your password and a database name (I just use `Cluster0` as the `<dbname>` even though i don't have a database called that, some earlier MongoDB documentation said to use that I think), and paste it in the `From SRV` field and click the `From SRV` field button.  It will automatically populate all the required fields and then you can `Test` it and then click `Save`.

Comment: This helped me. Enter the connection string hit From SRV button and it will populate all the required fields. Change the connection name and hit save.

Answer (score 12):

@kdblue, It's not working for me. But when I tried using the replica set, I could able to connect successfully.

Robo 3T Version: **1.2.1**

Steps followed:

In your MongoDB Atlas(cloud.mongodb.com), copy all the three replica sets name and note it down. (Refer an image for reference, the replica sets denoted in the orange box).

[image]

Now, in your Robo 3T, in Connection tab, select type as Replica Set.
Provide a suitable name for your connection.
And now in Members, add all the three copied replica sets. Refer image for details.

[image]

Provide authentication, if you have any and follow SSL steps (**mandatory**) as suggested by @**kdblue** in the previous answer.

You could able to connect successfully now.

Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me :) , I did not have set Access from anywhere but instead I whitelisted only my IP in Atlas and connected using Direct Connection, it is slow compared to the direct shell access, but works. Thanks @Balasubramani

Comment: I get SSL tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or SSL connection rejected by server.

Answer (score 4):

[Updated]

It is now possible to connect to Mongo Atlas 3.4 free cluster with the latest beta: [Robomongo 1.1 - Beta version with MongoDB 3.4 Support](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250#issuecomment-301036770)

Comment: Thanks Gokhan, one more thing when i m trying to connect mlab sandbox getting authorize error. I found https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/949 . but still same problem for me. is there any update on same?

Comment: I suggest to create a new github ticket with OS & Robomongo version, error window (message) and your connection settings details for investigation. I do not think there is a quick answer for that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Direct connections do not work with Replica Sets and Robo3T.
And the cluster you create on Atlas is a 3-Node replica set.

Select Connection Type: **Replica Set** on the first tab

To find out 3 members in new Atlas dashboard:

1. click on **Clusters** in your Atlas dashboard.
2. click **collections** button on the cluster.
3. click **Overview** tab on the next menu.

you will see the list of your set (primary and two secondary).

then follow @Balasubramani M's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the "TLS" instead of the "SSL" tab, don't get crazy.

Just do exactly the same that you would do with "SSL":

1. Mark the "Use TLS protocol" checkbox
2. Choose the "Self-signed Certificate" authentication method option

And that's all!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting it with robomongo I would recommend you to connect it with COMPASS. That is a opensource GUI tool for connecting to your MongoDB Atlas deployment and it is supported by MongoDB people also.

You can download compass from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass.

Additionally many functionalities are not supported in robomongo.

Robo mongo is the 3rd party tool so even if you go the mongodb people they will not support.

Instruction for connecting your atlas cluster with compass can be found in the documentation https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/compass-connection/

However, even after following my response you encounter any issue, let me know , I will help you further.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what I tried it wouldn't work, all I had to end up doing was update to the latest version at which point my old connection setup worked fine.

https://robomongo.org/download

Answer (score -1):

Tip: I struggled updating a connection, no dice.

Created one form scratch using above and connected on first attempt.