# Connecting robomongo/root3t with monogo atlas

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to connect to mongo atlas using root3t.
But when I try to use connection url root 3t says invalid 'Error:
Path to unix socket too long'.

Please help

Comment: Can you post more details? Error says your unix/linux socket domain length is too large. Can you post your connection url? I guess its length is more than the threshold vale set at OS level.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694799/how-can-i-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-using-robomongo

Answer (score 0):

Your Robo3T version will be 1.2 or older. Upgrade it to version 1.3 or newer.
Then do following 
[image: Use this SRV]

Remember to replace the user in the connection string and the pass at Authentication Tab